# How can one-way hash functions in the signatures help by using same algorithm for encryption and signature verification?

Tags: signature, one-way-function, hash-signature

I read some documents about digital signatures and one way hash functions, etc., but everything was too complicated and I don't have much experience in cryptography. Can anyone explain to me in a simpler way why this is possible?

By digital confirmations of receipt, whenever Bob has received a message, he sends it back as confirmation.

---

**SA** - Alice's digital Signature

**EA** - Alice's public key (for encryption)

**DA** - Alice's private key (for decryption)

**SB** - Bob's digital Signature

**EB** - Bob's public key (for encryption)

**DB** - Bob's private key (for decryption)

**VA** and **VB** are used functions for verification.

---

**1.** Alice signs, encrypts and sends *EB (SA (m))*.

**2.** Bob decrypts and verifies the signature *VA (DB (EB (SA (m)))) = M*.

**3.** Bob signs M with his private key, then encrypts it with Alice's public key and sends the whole thing back to Alice

*EA (SB (m))*.

**4.** Alice decrypts and verifies the signature. If the messages match, Bob received the message correctly.

---

If the same algorithm is used for encryption and signature verification (Vx = Ex and Sx = Dx), there is a possible attack.

### QUESTION

Why can, through the use of one-way hash functions in the signatures, this attack be prevented even if the above requirement is met?

Comment: Nice question (nearly there). It's true that, in public-key a.k.a. asymmetric-key cryptography, using the same key for both digital signature and public-key encryption are avoided. But the current form of this question makes it easy to attract answers that may not pin-point your confusion. So would you consider posting links to the documents you're reading?

Comment: I read about it in my class script and I read these answers. But I can't connect them together. Why should one-way-function help. What is the main point in the attack where this function helps?
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112685/how-do-one-way-hash-functions-work-edited

Comment: What about studying how this is done in RSA? See RSAES-OAEP and RSASSA-PSS in [PKCS#1v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf). Both use hash functions to turn textbook RSA into secure encryption and secure signature. Although I know no formal proof of that, RSAES-OAEP and RSASSA-PSS will work safely in the context's question even if (contrary to best practices) the same key is used for decryption and signature.

Comment: @fgrieu Using RSASSA-PSS in the given question, there is no way for Bob to recover the message $M$ tho.

Comment: @Manish Adhikari: yes, if SA produces only the RSASSA-PSS signature. I'm intending that SA produce the concatenation of the message and it's RSASSA-PSS signature, which fixes that problem. Also, when using RSAES-OAEP for EB, we must either split things over several cryptograms or use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem); either is fine.